# Can't Find My Derailleur Hanger

Tags: shimano, derailleur-rear, hanger

My Derailleur Hanger broke and I want to replace it. However, I couldn't find any information about my bike or model or what kind of hanger I need to buy. The brand is Esperia and model name is Aria.

Here is the photo of the broken hanger:

[image: Broken Hanger]

I even tried calling the seller, they said they can't help me with that since they are just resellers.

So, I tried to check the bike to see if I can find anything helpful and I saw that speed gear was Shimano RD-2300. Is the hanger special to this Shimano model, If no how can I find the correct hanger for my bike?

Comment: The hanger is specific to the bike frame.  Tell us what bike frame you have, or post a picture of that.

Comment: A decent LBS will have a collection of RD hangers to chose from.

Comment: If they don't stock it most shops have a wall chart  with 200 or so "to scale" pictures they can match it to.

Comment: Yeah. You can also look online at http://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hangers.html

Comment: @takobaba -  I'd take it to a bike shop so they can match it to the chart they have. It's very easy to get a hanger that looks similar but isn't quite right unless you find it by the bike's model number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct derailleur hanger for my bike frame:

[Derailleur Hanger suits some Avanti, Schwinn, Diamond Back, Fuji, Jamis HG007](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/371898617010)

[image: Derailleur Hanger suits some Avanti, Schwinn, Diamond Back, Fuji, Jamis HG007e]

Answer (score 1):

Yours rotated looks like [image]

Best I could find is http://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hanger-6.html 
which is "similar" but the mount holes look too large, the duck bill is way wrong, and the curve is there but wrong.

The holes might kill it, but its possible the other parts aren't critical.

[image]

Don't bother with the emergency hangers for long term use - they don't last long and they don't work well.

Comment: Your option now is take it into a LBS and ask for "what's close enough" ?

Comment: I think I found the perfect fit. Thanks anyways. http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/371898617010

Comment: @takobaba - If you did find the correct derailleur hanger, you should answer your own question (and accept) so that the thread can be closed.