# Trying to find Derailleur hanger for a custom road frame

Tags: derailleur-rear, derailleur-hanger

[image: VBT custom road frame derailleur hanger mount]

Hi everyone, I'm trying to find out which derailleur hanger to order for this frame I was given. A friend at a local co-op had this frame lying around, and it needs a hanger before I can install a rear mech. Does anyone have any idea which style of hanger would fit? The one in this post: [POST](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/46964/cant-find-my-derailleur-hanger) looks like a possibility, but the hook bit at the end looks like it points the wrong direction. If I strike out, I'll go to a local bike shop, but they'll charge an arm and a leg in New Zealand for that part, and from previous experience won't give me a part number or specific info about the hanger.

Cheers!

Comment: If you don't want to go to a shop, you can match to a chart at a place like [WheelsMfg](http://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hangers.html).

Comment: Find a better LBS - go for one that stocks non-race bikes and where the sales floor feels crowded instead of one that stocks running shoes/clothes and has wide empty aisles.

Comment: Are you in Christchurch ?

Comment: Yep, Wheels Mfg sells a good variety of hangers and has a "guaranteed fit" service.

Comment: Ahh, No, I'm in Wellington. I think I know a LBS that might fit the bill.

Comment: As your ion NZ, head over to vorb.org.nz and ask there.  You will at least get pointed to a decent LBS in Wellington.

Comment: Well after all this trouble, I picked up a box of old bike parts from the recycle centre today, and there on an old Tiagra rear mech was the hanger I needed! And yes, it is exactly like the Wheels Mfg #31. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it might be Hanger #31 from Wheels Manufacturing:
http://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hangers/1-fastener-derailleur-hangers/derailleur-hanger-31.html
It's a little tough to see in your photo, but that's the closest I could find.
 [image]

Comment: I think that's probably right. The notchy part on the left tip in the picture above is pretty unique.

Comment: Thanks, that actually looks the closest out of anything else I've seen.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you've searched for the manufacturer?  If they still exist you might contact them for information on what you need.

Failing that, you could try the Wheels Manufacturing site, as mentioned in the post you referenced.  Were you to send them a photo of the dropout, perhaps including a ruler overlaid atop the dropout, they might be able to help you.

Comment: The trouble is, VBT currently uses Fuji frames, but I've looked up the hangers for fuji frames and none of them look like they would fit. That leads me to believe that this is probably not a Fuji, so I'm at a loss as to who the original manufacturer was. I'll try to contact Wheels and see if they'll clear it up. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MarkNoyes So why don't you ask VBT? They presumably know what they did before they started using Fujis?

Comment: I'm 90% sure it's the hanger in the answer above (Wheels Mfg #31) so I've got one coming in and I'll confirm once I've tried it out.

Answer (score 1):

the Wheels #31 hanger was indeed the right one.

Comment: Looks like you've registered a second account, different to the one used to post the question.